# Number of solutions to $n^2 \equiv 444 \pmod{1000}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

An interesting problem from an elementary number theory textbook:

If $n \leqslant 2020$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then how many positive integers $n$ satisfy the equation

$$n^2 \equiv 444 \pmod{1000}$$

This seems quite elementary but tricky. I have tried factoring and using Euler's totient theorem and at the end it seems like there is only one solution (that is $n = 38$), however I'm not completely sure if this is true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which elementary number theory textbook?

Comment: 104 problems in number theory by Titu Andressccu

Comment: If $n$ is a solution then $1000-n$, $1000+n$, $2000-n$ are also solutions.

Comment: Does it help to get all solutions? Thanks.

Comment: number of solutions is infinite; general form of solutions is $38+ 1000 t$. But congruence must have two primitive roots.

Answer (score 2):

We need $$n^2\equiv444\pmod8\equiv4\iff n\equiv2\pmod4\ \ \ \ (1)$$

and
$$n^2\equiv444\pmod{125}$$

Use Hensel's [Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Alternative_statement) to find  $$n\equiv\pm38\pmod{125}\ \ \ \ (2)$$  starting $n^2\equiv444\pmod5\equiv4\implies n\equiv\pm2\pmod5$

Now apply [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) on $(1),(2)$

Comment: @BookWick, Please find the updated post

Answer (score 1):

$n^2\equiv 444 \pmod{8} \implies n^2\equiv 4 \pmod{8} \implies (n+2)(n-2)\equiv 0 \pmod{8}$
Hence we get $n\equiv 2,6 \pmod{8}.$

$n^2\equiv 444 \pmod{125}.$

We first solve the congruence modulo $5$, then modulo $5^2$, and then finally modulo $5^3$.

$n^2\equiv 444 \pmod{5} \implies n^2\equiv 4 \pmod{5} \implies (n+2)(n-2)\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$
Hence we get $n\equiv 2,3 \pmod{5}.$
For sake of simplicity, let consider the case of $n\equiv 2 \pmod{5}.$

Next we lift to find the solutions modulo $5^2$.
Any solution must be of the form $n=2+5a$  for some $a$.

Substitute  $n=2+5a$ to $n^2\equiv 444 \pmod{25}.$
We get $a\equiv 2 \pmod{5}.$

Similarly, substitute  $a=2+5b$ to $n^2\equiv 444 \pmod{125}.$
We get $b\equiv 3 \pmod{5}.$

Hence we get the solution $n\equiv 87 \pmod{125}.$
We get another solution $n\equiv -87 \equiv 38 \pmod{125}.$

Using Chinese Remainder Theorem, we get four solutions with $n<1000$ as follows.

$n\equiv 2 \pmod{8}$ and $n\equiv 38 \pmod{125} \implies n\equiv 538 \pmod{1000}.$
$n\equiv 2 \pmod{8}$ and $n\equiv 87 \pmod{125} \implies n\equiv 962 \pmod{1000}.$
$n\equiv 6 \pmod{8}$ and $n\equiv 38 \pmod{125} \implies n\equiv 38 \pmod{1000}.$
$n\equiv 6 \pmod{8}$ and $n\equiv 87 \pmod{125} \implies n\equiv 462 \pmod{1000}.$

We get above result using PARI-GP as follows.

```
           c1= chinese( Mod(2,8), Mod(38,125) );
           c2= chinese( Mod(2,8), Mod(87,125) );
           c3= chinese( Mod(6,8), Mod(38,125) );
           c4= chinese( Mod(6,8), Mod(87,125) );
           print([c1,c2,c3,c4]);

           [Mod(538, 1000), Mod(962, 1000), Mod(38, 1000), Mod(462, 1000)]
```